# how to support search in DynamoDB similar to LIKE functionality in ORACLE

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I need to support a use case where i need to search all attributes that are INPUT given by the user. As DynamoDB doesn't supports regular expression and a full scan is not possible overtime on that attributes. How should i move forward. Users will be calling that functionality quiet often.

Comment: Keep a copy of the data in ElasticSearch? You aren't going to have fun trying to build that functionality onto DynamoDB.

Comment: @MarkB : If using streams and Lambda we move Data to Elastic Search. what will be the average latency for programatic 'get' on various indexes in ELastic search?

Comment: I've been working on a PoC of this for something at my job, I'm seeing a delay of at most a couple seconds. But we have a slightly more complex pipe than just DDB -λ-> ES.